# Laravel Response::json not returning JSON properly?

Tags: json, laravel

Routes registered in `app/routes.php`

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController',
    array('except' => array('new', 'update')));

Route::post('users/authenticate', array('as' => 'authenticate', 'uses' => 'UsersController@authenticate'));

Route::get('users/is_authenticated', array('as' => 'authenticated', 'uses' => 'UsersController@is_authenticated'));
```

The method is_authenticated is not returning JSON, but when I put the `Response::json()` in the `index` method it returns the JSON schema.

Here is my `is_authenticated` method:

```
public function is_authenticated()
{
    return Response::json(['authenticated' => Auth::check()]);
}
```

What's going wrong here?  I ran `php artisan routes` and it returns this for the route:

`GET|HEAD api/users/is_authenticated | authenticated     | UsersController@is_authenticated`

I don't get a 404 Not Found when visiting the page, but there is no content.  What's the problem?

Edit: routes are prefixed with `api`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your first route is activated when calling `users/is_authenticated`. The order of the routes is important in Laravel, as the first matching route is executed. You can just change the order of your routes to make the route `users/is_authenticated` available, like so:

```
Route::post('users/authenticate', array('as' => 'authenticate', 'uses' => 'UsersController@authenticate'));

Route::get('users/is_authenticated', array('as' => 'authenticated', 'uses' => 'UsersController@is_authenticated'));

Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', array('except' => array('new', 'update')));
```